# Literal question mark in mod_rewrite target

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of files that are literally named `file.txt?x=1&y=2` sitting in an apache directory. I want requests to `http://example.net/sub/file.txt?x=1&y=2` serve these files instead of trying to show `http://example.net/sub/file.txt` with the query path `x=1&y=2`.

If possible, I'd also like being able to serve `file.doc` (without any question marks) as well as serve requests with the correctly encoded filename (i.e. `http://example.net/sub/file.txt%3Fx=1&y=2`).

How can I configure the .htaccess file in the sub/ directory to do that using mod_rewrite? The obvious rule

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

results in a straight passthrough because mod_rewrite sees `?` as a query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the question mark as `%3F` **and mask it with a backslash**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^[^?]*$ $0\%3F%{QUERY_STRING}
```

The [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) ensures that URLs without a query string do not get a question mark appended to them. The [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) only matches when they aren't any correctly encoded question marks already.